# Should I use Singleton or Scoped service for making api calls in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection

I have a class for making API calls. I would like to pass it as dependency and I want to know if it is better to use `Singleton` or `Scoped` :

```
services.AddScoped<IHttpCallService, HttpCallService>();
 or 
services.AddSingleton<IHttpCallService, HttpCallService>();
```

I know there are differences between Singleton and Scoped in terms of instance creation,
but I would like to know which one is more efficient and suitable for this case?
And also, if I use `Singleton`, would it mean that everything would work synchronously?

Comment: Maybe this will help you understand better : [Dependency injection in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Comment: What kind of application are you talking about?

Comment: If you are using an HttpClient... The best approach is use a singleton and make your cals using async/await.  HttpClient is designed to work better that way anyways.

Comment: @AlexeyRumyantsev this is an asp.net core web Api application.

Comment: Regarding "would it mean that everything would work synchronously?": In C# there isn't any kind of queue for requests using the same object or method. If multiple threads are all using the same singleton object, each thread has its own stack and is basically independent. The only thing really shared is any fields on the singleton object.

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro Actually, I'm not sure about it, do you have any reference for it?

Comment: @NavidRsh this is a known fact. You can search it yourself on the internet. As a matter of fact if you create instances of HttpClient you can end up crashing your system due to socket starvation.  Just google it.

Comment: https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/ and http://byterot.blogspot.com/2016/07/singleton-httpclient-dns.html are two very useful resources. This is why [HttpClientFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-5.0) was implemented.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The recommomended pattern is to have your `HttpCallService` depend on an `HttpClient` instance, and then register it as a [Typed Client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-5.0#typed-clients) with

```
services.AddHttpClient<HttpCallService>();
```

This will register `HttpCallService` as a transient service.

Answer (score 0):

Best recommendation is to use `singleton` in this scenario when your dealing with with api calls. Below article explains what is the issue you don't use `HttpClient` as `singleton`

```
services.AddSingleton<IHttpCallService, HttpCallService>();
```

Read this article for more in depth knowledge on this
https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/httpclient-connection-pooling-in-dotnet-core